# Manga where the hero is sent back in time by a dragon

Tags: story-identification, manga, dragons

He and the dragon that sent him back him then work together to kill the dragon king or something like that. In the new timeline, the dragon that sent him back does not initially know him, but the hero gains her trust by showing her that he knows some things that there was no way he could have known. IIRC, the hero also manages to save a talented sword user girl that was his childhood friend or something in this new timeline. The enemy dragons all have ranks and there are some cool battles. The allied dragon that initially sent the hero back in time was undercover and other dragons do not know that she is/was working against them. Its was a shounen/seinen Japanese manga that was black and white.

This I'm less sure of but I think it was a monthly manga with 30-40 pages per chapter. May have read it on either mangadex or mangapark.

---

It's not:

- A Returner's Magic Should Be Special

Comment: @Valorum I dont believe this is the same story? The one linked seems like a manhwa instead.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Does the childhood friend swordswoman have a large scar on her face? Does the story perspective change with the time travel, or is it a case of the main character gaining knowledge and power from his future self?

Comment: @qazmlpok No to the first question. The story's perspective does not change. The hero is still the main character. As for the 2nd half, I can't exactly remember if he gained power from his future self or if he is his future self and was sent to the past directly.

Comment: Probably not Ragna Crimson, then. The scar's pretty distinctive. However, the other details do seem like a good match after reading another chapter, so I would still suggest giving it a look.

Comment: Another chapter and it's such a close match that I'm pretty certain this is it, despite not remembering a scar. There could still be another swordswoman, or maybe she gets healed.

Comment: @qazmlpok oh damn it was ragna crimson I just didnt rememebr there was a scar. Thank you so much! Was looking for this for quite a while

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is most likely [Ragna Crimson](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/ragna-crimson).

> ... humanity lives under the threat of annihilation by immensely powerful dragons. The dragon hunter Ragna embarks on a revenge-fueled quest to eliminate that threat once and for all. Dragon hunters: warriors armed with special silver weapons who kill their prey for bounty. Lowest among their ranks is Ragna, who forms an improbable partnership with the young genius Leonica, a master dragon slayer with more kills to her name than almost any other.

Not mentioned in the description is the time travel element; Ragna has dreams/visions of Leonica dying, and later receives immense power from his future self, 20 years into the future, after Leo dies. He uses this power to save her in the present.

I believe the time travel was initiated by the traitorous dragon Crimson, but I haven't seen this confirmed in the first few chapters. They do partner up in the future, and by chance he runs into her again in the present. She doesn't believe his tales of being from the future at first and denies being a dragon.

[image: Crimson denying being a dragon]

Dragons also have ranks;

[image: Mention of ranks]

Chapters are long, with around 50-60 pages each.

Comment: How did you get it so quickly? Based on the comments it doesn't sound like you've read it before.

Comment: @SquareTom Mangaupdates tag search; the combination of "time travel" and "dragon/s", filtered to manga only. Then just going through the list for something that sounded vaguely right.